# how to transfer globals to functions and how to calculate the input of arrays?

Tags: c

I am suppoused not to use globals just functions. I don't know where to have  int measurements[LENGTH], x, i; to work as it does. I also need a function to calculate de number of measurements(nrOfMeasurements) that user typed in in getMeasurements. for example if they typed in 4 instead f 10. This is needed for ex. to calculate the average.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define LENGTH 10

const char *IntroMsg = "\n\t Hello To TEST THE PRGRAM!\n",
           *MenuMsg = "\n\t Menu \n\t v (View) \n\t e (Enter) \n\t c (Compute) \n\t r (Reset) \n\t q (Quit) \n\n";

int    measurements[LENGTH],//not here
       x, i;//not here

void getMeasurements(){
    for(x=0; x<LENGTH; x++){
        printf("Enter number #%d: ", x+1);
        scanf("%d", &measurements[x]);

        if(measurements[x]==0){
            break;
    }
    }
    return; 
}

void getView(){
    printf("\t\n");
    printf("Your measurements:\n");
    if(x>0){
        for (i = 0; i < x; i++){        
        printf("\b %d ", measurements[i]);
        }
    }
    else if(x==0){
        printf(" [NO MEASUREMENTS]");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void getCompute(){
    int min = INT_MAX;
    int max = INT_MIN;
    int calculus;
    float sum;
    for(x=0; x<LENGTH; x++){
            if (measurements[x]<min) min=measurements[x];
            if (measurements[x]>max) max=measurements[x];
            sum=sum+measurements[x];

            calculus= measurements[x] - (sum/LENGTH);
            printf("[%d]", calculus);
    }
    printf("\nMax number: %d", max);
    printf("\nMin number: %d", min);
    printf("\nAverage: %.2f", sum/LENGTH);
    printf("\n\n");
}   
int main(){

    while(1){
        char choice;
        puts (MenuMsg);
        scanf(" %c", &choice);

        if(choice=='e')
            getMeasurements();

        else if(choice=='v'){
            getView();
        }   

        else if(choice=='c'){
            getCompute();
        }   

        else if(choice=='q'){
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pass the variables as parameters to the relevant functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 10

const char *IntroMsg = "\n\t Hello To TEST THE PROGRAM!\n";
const char *MenuMsg  = "\n\t Menu \n"
                         "\t v (View)\n"
                         "\t e (Enter)\n"
                         "\t c (Compute)\n"
                         "\t r (Reset)\n"
                         "\t q (Quit)\n\n";

int getMeasurements(int *measurements, int length) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("Enter number #%d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &measurements[i]);
        if(measurements[i] == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return i;
}

void getView(const int *measurements, int length){
    int i;

    printf("\t\nYour measurements:\n");
    if (length == 0) {
        printf(" [NO MEASUREMENTS]\n");
        return;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("\b %d ", measurements[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void getCompute(const int *measurements, int length) {
    int min, max, calculus, i;
    float sum = 0;

    if (length == 0) {
        printf(" [NO MEASUREMENTS]\n");
        return;
    }

    min = max = measurements[0];
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++){
            if (measurements[i] < min) min = measurements[i];
            if (measurements[i] > max) max = measurements[i];
            sum += measurements[i];
            calculus = measurements[i] - (sum / length);
            printf("[%d]", calculus);
    }
    printf("\nMax number: %d", max);
    printf("\nMin number: %d", min);
    printf("\nAverage: %.2f", sum / length);
    printf("\n\n");
}

int main() {
    int measurements[MAX_LENGTH];
    int measurements_count = 0;
    int run = 1;

    while (run) {
        char choice;
        puts(MenuMsg);
        scanf(" %c", &choice);

        switch (choice) {
        case 'e':
            measurements_count = getMeasurements(measurements, MAX_LENGTH);
            break;
        case 'v':
            getView(measurements, measurements_count);
            break;
        case 'c':
            getCompute(measurements, measurements_count);
            break;
        case 'q':
            run = 0;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Wrong input\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```